# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError dump to json

Tags: json, ruby, encoding

I'm working with a gem [fie](https://fie.eranpeer.co/) and ran into an issue with this gem that I would like to solve however I'm having trouble doing so. Fie is a gem for Rails. In it, it has some lines where it stores a marshal dump of an `ActiveRecord::Base` in json however I'm running in to an encoding error. I Have been able to replicate this across different machines and versions of ROR, although Rails 5.2 and greater.

Easiest way to reproduce is:

```
[5] pry(main)> Marshal.dump(User.first).to_json
  User Load (29.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
from /home/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:38:in `encode'
```

Digging In I tried a few things but was unable to make it work. It seems that a marshal dump is ASCII-8BIT but Json ants UTF-8bit. I was unable to force the encoding.

```
> User.first.to_json.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
> Marshal.dump(User.first).encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
> { foo: Marshal.dump(object).force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").encode("UTF-8") }.to_json
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
from (pry):139:in `encode'
> { foo: Marshal.dump(object).force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("ASCII-8BIT") }.to_json
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+0080 to ASCII-8BIT in conversion from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 to ASCII-8BIT
```

ruby 2.5.1
Rails 5.2.1

git [issue](https://github.com/raen79/fie/issues/27) I opened

Comment: What is object here? Do you have a standalone way to reproduce this?

Comment: `Marshal.dump` produces binary data and binary data is usually Base64 encoded in JSON. Are you really sure that you want to use `Marshal` for this?

Comment: What does this question have to do with JSON? Presumably you can reproduce the error with a more **Minimal** example: `Marshal.dump(object).force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT").encode("UTF-8")`?  Now then, what is `object`? How can we reproduce this? And what are you actually trying to achieve>

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: @maxpleaner any thoughts.

Comment: @ChrisCPO not sure, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and fixed it by using:

```rb
Marshal.dump(value).force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
```

I hope this help!

But as [Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord) suggested you should be a bit more specific with your question to help us know what you are trying to achieve.